# Url rewrite for subdomain as Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, asp.net-4.0

first of all i do not have enough experience with Url rewriting in asp.net. Anyways i pulled url rewriting thanks to SO and other helpful articles over internet. But this new project have a specific need, i have to show Url for different users as:

> username.domainname.topdomain

further more every action for user specific pages should work like this i.e. for user profile.aspx page instead of :

> domain.topdomain/username/profile.aspx

we want:

> username.domainname.topdomain/profile/

how can i pull this out?
Regards

P.S. the request can have "N" number of querystrings ,so anything in web.config or so will be too complex to handle.

Comment: Have you actually got DNS entries for every username.domainname.topdomain?

Comment: no, no DNS level entries. We just have to fake that url (as virtual path i guess??).

Comment: agree with @DD59 I don't see how to achieve this without DNS handling

Comment: so that means we cant fake it without DNS handling, well in that case it would be too much to create new subdomains every time a user register with our site, is their a way through which asp.net can register subdomain on DNS . i am using Godaddy and arvixe shared hosting

Comment: you don't need to register a DNS subdomain for each of your user. Use a wildcard subdomain *.domainname.topdomain (see http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1410/how-to-programmatically-create-dynamic-subdomains-on-iis.aspx )

Comment: ok i am looking into the issue

Comment: alright but even this example doesnt show me how to handle it and i am asking about a beginner level example for routing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //DLL: Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll    

    //web.config
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
        <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
      </configSections>
    </configuration>

    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>


    <rewriter>
        <rewrite url="~/(.+)/CompanyHomePage" to="~/Home.aspx"/>
    </rewriter>


    //C#:

     string strTitle = Session["company_name"].ToString();
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');
     strTitle = strTitle.ToLower();
     char[] chars = @"$%#@!*?;:~`+=()[]{}|\'<>,/^&"".".ToCharArray();
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("c#", "C-Sharp");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("vb.net", "VB-Net");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("asp.net", "Asp-Net");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace(".", "-");

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        string strChar = chars.GetValue(i).ToString();
        if (strTitle.Contains(strChar))
        {
           strTitle = strTitle.Replace(strChar, string.Empty);
        }
    }
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace(" ", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("-----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim();
     strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');

     Response.Redirect("~/" + strTitle + "/CompanyHomePage", false);//Redirect to ~/Home.aspx page


//reference: CompanyHomePage same in web.config  <rewrite url="~/(.+)/CompanyHomePage" to="~/Home.aspx"/> which company is log in to sight that company name show in url like this http://abcd//CompanyHomePage
```

Comment: you give your mail id.i will send sample program

Comment: hello ran your code, it is just plain urlrewrite not what i am seeking or should i say half of what i am seeking . Anyways thanks it will help me minimizing my future coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The HttpContext class in Asp.Net will not help you with this one. The rewriter methods on that are intended to cover the path and query string, not the hostname or port.
I believe you will need to use a client-side re-write in order to change the hostname: send some script to the client to reload from a different location.

As others have said, you will need to have some wildcard DNS setup to allow your username.domain.tld hostnames resolve to your web server.